# Canonical way to write gradle task for adding new Android product flavors

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-productflavors

I want to automate work with flavors in Android project, using custom Gradle tasks.
For example, implement `addFlavor` task with 2 parameters: `flavorName` and `flavorLogo`. The task should add new flavor, by making next steps:

1. Update `productFlavors` section in `build.gradle` file, by adding a new flavor to it:

   ```groovy
   flavorName {
      buildConfigField 'String', 'PARTNER', '"flavorName"'
      packageName 'com.stackoverflow.askquestion.flavorname'
   }
   ```
2. Add flavor folder and copy `flavorLogo` `.png` file to `flavorName/res/drawable-xxhdpi/ic_launcher.png`

What is the correct and canonical way to do it with custom a Gradle task?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use tasks to create Flavors. Flavors describe the model used to create tasks, so it won't work the other way around.

However, you can diretly put code in your build.gradle that will create this for you everytime the build.gradle is executed (basically everytime you run a Gradle command). You could write something like:

```
String[] customFlavors = ['flavor1', 'flavor2']

customFlavors.each { name ->
    def flavor = android.productFlavors.create(name)
    flavor.buildConfigField('String', 'PARTNER', "\"${name}\""
    flavor.packageName("com.so.question.${name}")
}
```